# Bootstrap 4 items instead of 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Looking at [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/), forget the menu on the right.

I would like to know how can I have 4 **headings** instead of 3 per line?

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y2Nj/1/).

Is there anything we can change on class?

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <h2></h2>
    <p>whatever</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4y2Nj/2/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 12 columns per row so if you set `col-lg-3` then 4 will fit into one row (for large screens)

Please read this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid